# How to wait for two async functions to end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, asynchronous

I have 2 promises functions in an if-else statement.

```js
if(file_type == "pdf"){
  // Some Promise
  .then(data =>
    result = data;
  )
}
else{
  // Other Promise
  .then(data => 
    result = data
  )
}
// Do something with the data
```

What I want is that the last part that is synchronous should not happen before executing the promise but I don't want to repeat the synchronous code in both the `then` blocks of the promises. Is there a way to do so?

What I tried was

```js
async() => { if(file_type == "pdf"){
  await // Some Promise
  .then(data =>
    result = data;
  )
}
else{
  await // Other Promise
  .then(data => 
    result = data
  )
}
}
// Do something with the result
```

But the approach didn't work. It straight away skipped the async part.

Sorry if it is a very dumb question. I search for it on YouTube and StackOverflow, but all in vain. **Thanks for any help**.

Comment: When you use `await`, you don't use `.then()`. You could just do something like this:
`var result = await somePromise();`. Also, make sure you are calling your `async` function.

Comment: @LuketheGeek How do I call a nameless async function?

Comment: Define your function and call it right after:
`(async () => { /* do some async stuff here */ })();`.
 Note the `()` after the function definition. This is called a **Immediately-invoked Function Expressions (IIFE)**. See https://flaviocopes.com/javascript-iife/ for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the conditional operator to reference `Some Promise` or `Other Promise`, then call `.then` on that Promise:

```
const prom = file_type == 'pdf' ? somePromise : otherPromise;
prom.then((data) => {
  // Do something with the data
});
```

Make sure to put all functionality that depends on the asynchronous info *inside* the `.then` callback, not outside. Don't assign to an outside variable.

You can also put it into a named function:

```
const processData = (data) => {
  // Do something with the data
};
const prom = file_type == 'pdf' ? somePromise : otherPromise;
prom.then(processData);
```

Comment: Yes, but you are not using `await` here. It should be `const data = await (file_type == "pdf" ? somePromise : otherPromise);`.